# C# Generic Collections, IComparer, IComparable and IEquatable

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am working on a C# project where I make heavy use of interfaces, and the `System.Collections.Immutable` library. I wish to sort implementations of one of my interfaces in an immutable set, `ImmutableSortedSet<IMyInterface>`.

In Java this is a straightforward matter of implementing `Comparable<IMyInterface>` and overriding the equals and hash code functions. I found a similar interface in .net `IComparable<IMyInterface>` but it warns implementers that if they choose to implement the interface, then they should also override the comparison operators (<,>,<=,>=), as well as implement `IEquatable<IMyInterface>`. `IEquatable<T>` warns implementers that they should override the equals and hash code functions, as well as the '==' and '!=' operators.

Now I'm having second thoughts about implementing `IComparable<T>`, I'm not creating a new primitive type here, I just want to provide a convenient sorting algorithm for a complex reference type. Furthermore, there seems to be a certain problem in C# with overriding operators at the interface level, I am therefore leaning towards using a separate `IComparer<IMyInterface>` implementation.

What really raised my eyebrows though was hearing this:

> The `IEquatable<T>` interface is used by generic collection objects such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `List<T>`, and `LinkedList<T>` when testing for equality in such methods as `Contains`, `IndexOf`, `LastIndexOf`, and `Remove`. It should be implemented for any object that might be stored in a generic collection.

Does this combined with

> If you implement `IEquatable<T>`, you should also override the base class implementations of `Object.Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode` so that their behavior is consistent with that of the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method. If you do override `Object.Equals(Object)`, your overridden implementation is also called in calls to the static `Equals(System.Object, System.Object)` method on your class. In addition, you should overload the op_Equality and op_Inequality operators. This ensures that all tests for equality return consistent results.

Mean that I am expected to override both '==' and '!=' operators for any type that I want to store inside a generic collection??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IComparable<T>` is the preferred mechanism to provide comparison support for sorting.  The advice of implementing the comparison operators doesn't make a lot of sense for most types, and they could not be utilized by generic collections anyway.  You should also implement `IEquatable<T>`, override `GetHashCode()`, and override `object.Equals` to delegate to `IEquatable<T>.Equals`.

In general, whenever I implement `IComparable<T>`, I also implement the non-generic `IComparable`, but I implement `IComparable.CompareTo` explicitly such that it is normally hidden.

Comment: Now I'm curious why generic collections would not be able to use the overloaded comparison operators, does it have something to do with not knowing the value of the generic type at compile time from within the generic class?

Comment: There's no way to know that the operator in question is actually implemented for the all possible type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, if you need sorting, you can pass `IComparer<T>` implementation and your type doesn't have to implement `IComparable<T>`. In some cases it's easier and in some cases it's the only way to go, e.g. when you want the same type to be sorted differently in different situations. You can just pass different `IComparer<T>` implementations in that case.

About `IEquatable<T>` related quotes. For most situations overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is enough. It will make your type work with `List<T>.Contains` and similar methods. It will also allow you to use your type as key in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and store it in `HashSet<T>`. That's because all these cases use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` when comparer is not specified.

The way `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` works can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,542680fa5b2d828d). As you can see it verifies that your type implements `IEquatable<T>`, but if it doesn't creates an instance of `ObjectEqualityComparer<T>`, which will just use `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to verify equality.